# Spring integration Message handler chain usage?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am new to spring integration. i have few channels configured in my configuration file as below.

```
<int:channel id="channelOne" />
<int:channel id="channelTwo" />
<int:channel id="channelThree" />
```

can i use MessageHandlerChain ( http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/docs/2.0.0.RC1/reference/html/chain.html ) in this scenario?

Thanks!

Comment: Generally, you have 2 channels defined, an input and output channel.  Can you explain further what you're trying to do...

Comment: @tjg184, i have one input channel and output channel but have one more channel (channelTwo) in between input and output channel which does some sort of validation. can i use message handler chain in this scenario

Answer (score 14):

A chain is a convenience to simplify configuration when endpoints are connected by direct channels:

Instead of

```
<int:channel id="foo1"/>

<int:service-activator input-channel="foo1" output-channel="foo2" ref="s1" />

<int:channel id="foo2"/>

<int:service-activator input-channel="foo2" output-channel="foo3" ref="s2/>

<int:channel id="foo3"/>

<int:service-activator input-channel="foo3" output-channel="foo4" ref="s3" />

<int:channel id="foo4"/>
```

You can use

```
<int:channel id="foo1"/>

<int:chain input-channel="foo1" output-channel="foo4">    
    <int:service-activator ref="s1" />
    <int:service-activator ref="s2" />
    <int:service-activator ref="s3" />
</int:chain>

<int:channel id="foo4"/>
```

Please use the [current documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/).

Answer (score 3):

I would take a look at channel interceptors ([http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/htmlsingle/#channel-interceptors](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#channel-interceptors)).  These would allow you to do something prior to the message hitting your input channel, which I assume is channelOne.  You could log a message or throw an exception, etc. depending on your use case.

```
<channel id="channelOne">
    <interceptors>
        <ref bean="yourValidatingInterceptor"/>
    </interceptors>
</channel>

<beans:bean id="yourValidatingInterceptor" class="com.yourcompany.YourValidatingInterceptor"/>
```

Comment: Current release is 2.2.0: http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/docs/2.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#channel-interceptors, but it is better to use the 'latest-ga' link: http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/htmlsingle/#channel-interceptors

Answer (score 1):

we use **Message Handler Chain**  when a set of handlers needs to be 
connected in a linear fashion.

```
<int:chain input-channel="marketDataInputChannel"> 
    <int:splitter ref="marketDataSplitter"/> 
    <int:service-activator ref="marketFieldServiceActivator"/> 
    <int:aggregator ref="marketDataAggregator"/> 
    <int:service-activator ref="marketItemServiceActivator"/> 
</int:chain>
```

in the example above, the output data of channel **splitter** will be the input 
of **service-activator**, and the output of service-activator will be the input
of **aggregator** ...

I hope that this explanation help you to understand the utility of **`<int:chain />`**

Comment: You do not have an output-channel defined for this chain...I've seen this in other places and believe it is legit, but where does the output of your "marketItemServiceActivator" go?